# Addition function in Prolog

Tags: variables, prolog, addition, clpfd

Is there a way I can create a function for addition/3 which does that:
add(1,2,X) - X is 3.
add(1,X,3) - X is 2.
add(X,2,3) - X is 1.

Comment: Please see the [Stack Overflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a proper question. You need to show an attempt and ask specific questions about where you're stuck. As a hint to your problem, see Prolog CLPFD library.

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog, there is the predicate `plus/3` that does exactly that.

Comment: w/o any prolog extentions (in ISO prolog) you can use var/1 predicate to check is variable free or bound and perform the corresponding addition depending on what argument (1st, 2nd or 3d) is free

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, the best is to use `library(clpfd)` which provides all that functionality ; and even more than that. With

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We start, in SICStus you have now to tell `assert(clpfd:full_answer)`, then we have:

```
?- 1+2#=Z.
   Z = 3.
?- 1+Y#=3.
   Y = 2.
```

as you expected it. But even more than that!

```
?- X+X#=Z.
   2*X#=Z.
?- X+X#=X.
   X = 0.
?- X+Y#=Z.
   X+Y#=Z.
```